# Не подключается файл конфигурации в xampp, не диет подключение к oracle

Tags: php, oracle, apache, xampp, php.ini

Xampp не видит библиотеки .dll, в частности те, которые позволяют работать с Oracle. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Configuration File (php.ini) Path он спокойно читается и я могу менять ему путь. Но Loaded Configuration File, который судя по всему должен обязательно присутствовать, не показан даже в таблице phpinfo(); Почему xampp не видит oracle?

Comment: Вышел php 8, у вас 5.2. Не хотите обновиться?

Comment: Конечно нужно будет, но пока что главное чтобы php 5.2 могла спокойно работать с oracle